# Getting element id with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code should print the id of the selected div but it does not. I did not find the error. Thanks for help.

HTML

```
<body>
   <div id="form_area">
      <div>
         <button onclick="return add_row();" style="width:100%;">Add Row</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form_area div').click(function(e) {
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});

function add_row() {
    var random_id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1); 
    $('#form_area').prepend('<div id="' + random_id + '" class="form_row"></div>');
}
```

Comment: the div inside `#form_area` doesn't have an ID

Comment: When you are using jquery, why not use it consistently ? http://jsfiddle.net/tVPX8/2

Comment: @karthikr you forgot to remove the inline event handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I understand what you are missing. You are trying to log the `ID` after adding a row using `add_row` function,

`.form_row` is added dynamically to the DOM. So when executing `$('.form_row').click(`, there is no `.form_row` to bind the handler. The below way of using `.on` method binds the handler to `#form_area` and executes the handler only when the click event is from `.form_row`

```
$('#form_area').on('click', '.form_row', function () {
   console.log(this.id);
});
```

---

`$('#form_area div')` selects the `div` inside the div `#form_area` which doesn't have an `ID`

Below comment in html shows which div is selected,

```
<div id="form_area">
   <div>  <!-- $('#form_area div') selects this div-->
      <button onclick="return add_row();" style="width:100%;">Add Row</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried  $('.form_row').click(function(e) too but it did not work too.

Comment: @Cem There is no element with class `.form_row` in the HTML that you have posted.

Comment: $('#form_area').prepend... line adds them.

Comment: Thanks. $('#form_area').on('click', '.form_row', function () worked. But What is wrong with my method?

Comment: @Cem `.form_row` is added dynamically to the DOM. So when executing `$('.form_row').click(`, there is no `.form_row` to bind the handler. The above method in the answer binds the handler to `#form_area` and executes the handler only when the click event is from `.form_row`

Answer (score 0):

To access id use 'on' as your div is dynamically generated:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#form_area').on('click', '.form_row', function () {
        console.log(this.id);
    });
});
```

Comment: I add rows with add row button and when I click the new added rows, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have jQuery - you should use that to register your event handlers instead of using obsolete, error prone inline event handlers.

Secondly, your button handler is inside `#formarea` and so is also triggering the click handler since the button's parent has no ID.  This is probably not desired.

Thirdly, your event handlers need to be *delegated* because you're trying to catch events on dynamically added elements.

So, remove the `onclick` attribute and add this:

```
$('#formarea button').on('click', addRow);

$('#formarea').on('click', '.form_row', function() {  // delegated, for dynamic rows
    console.log(this.id);                            // NB: not $(this).attr('id') !!
});

function addRow(ev) {
    // unmodified
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/aZTbA/

Answer (score 0):

Try `console.log($('#form_area div').attr('id'));`